# Error local file using ServiceWorker with Blob in the Internet Explorer (only)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, service-worker

In Javascript, when using a service worker with a blob, only for IE, when I am using no local mode with the offline file (c: \ test.html), the error occurs. You can simulate with the code below:
new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([""])));

Running IE while inside a domain (eg: http: //localhost/index.html) works normally.
[image]

If it runs in IE while inside a physical physical (eg: C: \ inetpub \ wwwroot \ index.html) the error occurs, it says "invalid function".
[image]

In my case, my system generates a file and this is downloaded to the user, after that the user opens it physically on your PC (offline), I have no dependence on the internet, in case even firefox and chrome works perfectly, in the IE only works if I get the file and put in IIS and access via domain (localhost).

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by removing the word 'BLOB:' from the url, only for IE.

new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([""])).replace('blob:',''));

This worked both at http://localhost/ie.html and at c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ie.html

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had find the solution for your issue. I suggest you to mark your own answer as an accepted answer after 24 hrs may help other community members in future in similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.